# Hadoop - Analysing a network trafic streaming

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I need to know how to implement a solution for real-time analysing traffic streaming via Hadoop.

The input files type is .txt

I'm suggesting thoses steps :

1. Transfer flat files to HDFS with talend (is flume the better way than talend ? )
2. Transfer data from HDFS to Hive (but how)
3. Analysing via R

   flat file --> HDFS --> Hive --> R

Many thanks

Soufiane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If your date is already in stored in .txt files then "hadoop fs -cp" is good enough for you. Flume is for streaming data.

2) You don't need to transfer data from HDFS to Hive. Hive analyzes data that is stored in HDFS:

CREATE TABLE my_table (dummy STRING);

This defines a table.

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/tom/data.txt' INTO table my_table;

This will move your data into Hive’s warehouse directory. Since both directories are on HDFS it is done instantaneously.

3) For R check http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/